# Injecting services from serializable tokens in Angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to develop a component in Angular 16 that can customize its inner services via settings. I want this settings to be fully serializable, which would allow me to have something like this:

```
{
  service: 'MyCrudService',
  // ... rest of settings
}
```

I have managed to achieve this by adding providers that uses that same string names as injection tokens:

```
{ provide: 'MyCrudService', useExisting: MyCrudService },
```

Then, if I grab an instance of the correct injector, I usually can instance that service like this:

```
injector.get(this.settings.service)
```

The thing is, this way of instancing services is being deprecated, and the Angular core packages instructs that an actual provider token should be used instead of something like a string.

```
/**
  * Retrieves an instance from the injector based on the provided token.
  * @returns The instance from the injector if defined, otherwise the `notFoundValue`.
  * @throws When the `notFoundValue` is `undefined` or `Injector.THROW_IF_NOT_FOUND`.
  * @deprecated use object-based flags (`InjectOptions`) instead.
  */
abstract get<T>(token: ProviderToken<T>, notFoundValue?: T, flags?: InjectFlags): T;

/**
  * @deprecated from v4.0.0 use ProviderToken<T>
  * @suppress {duplicate}
  */
abstract get(token: any, notFoundValue?: any): any;
```

As far as I know, provider tokens are not serializable, so if Angular drops support for anything but provider tokens, my code will stop working. I could keep some kind of hash that maps me strings to injection tokens, like:

```
const map = new Map<string, InjectionToken<any>();
map.set('MyCrudService', new InjectionToken<any>('MyCrudService'));
```

Yet if does feel hacky and makes me wonder if I am following a good pattern. I know it has some limitation like type-checking the injected services, but I think it is sometimes worth the tradeoff. Does Angular support these kind of patterns in any other way, or should I better find other approach?

Comment: You'll hear that service locator pattern is an anti pattern in some circles, imo it's kind of mute point in Angular which has singular locator. Useful blog post https://nartc.me/blog/injection-token-service